# Installing pymol using macports on yosemite

Tags: xcode, macports

I tried to install pymol using macports (after trying to build from the source code failed):

```
sudo port install pymol
```

It did install it, giving me two warnings:

```
Warning: xcodebuild exists but failed to execute
Warning: Xcode does not appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
```

I am able to run pymol, but it crashes after a minute or so. Also, the top window does not show any buttons:

[image: pymol not working window buttons]

The error message is:

[image]

Is this because of the warnings `port` gave me at the very beginning, or is there something else at work here?

Comment: did you ever get this resolved? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case this ever helps someone, this will make it compile and load.

First *Uninstall Pymol*

Then:

```
% sudo port install tcl -corefoundation
% sudo port install tk -quartz
% sudo port install pymol
```

This is described here:

http://www.ub.edu/cbdd/?q=content/installing-pymol-macports

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that something else is at work.

The warnings are that you don't have Xcode (i.e., developer tools) installed. Many MacPorts packages require compiling, so you need the build environment.

It would really help to have the full crash window, because there are a lot of useful messages to developers.

What follows is complete speculation from someone who develops mixed Python and C/C++ open source code, much like PyMol.

My guess is that part of the PyMol code is linking against a different library that has changed under the Yosemite upgrade.

When I have multiple versions of Python installed, it can sometimes be tricky to make sure code is using the right version of libraries. This is *particularly* true across OS versions, since many libraries are upgraded by Apple.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I uploaded the full error message [here](http://iremaltan.com/error).

Comment: This seems to be a [known issue](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/46007) and not limited to PyMol, e.g., [PyCAM](https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?A2=ccpnmr;c9973177.1411).

Comment: I'd ask around on PyMol lists to see if there are any patches. Alternatively, this would be a good reason to get a supported version from Schrodinger. :-)